# Can't use Apple's new san francisco font. I am getting the following error "attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]"

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I am getting the following error

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
>   objects[0]'

The code below is what is causing this issue. The culprit as you can tell from the error is fontWithName. I am trying to use Apple's new Apple Watch font "San Francisco". Can anyone tell me how I can use Apple's new SanFrancisco font?

```
  attributeStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                        initWithString:string
                        attributes:@{
                                     NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"SanFranciscoText-Regular" size:10.0],
                                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:90.0/255.0 green:90.0/255.0 blue:90.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]
                                     }];
```

Comment: Are you trying to access from iOS, or WatchKit? Seems it's only available on the watch: http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: Access it from watchkit.

Answer (score 1):

Just check whether you font exists in device or simulator. and user the correct name of the font

```
NSLog (@"Font families: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);
```

Answer (score 0):

SanFranciscoDisplay-Regular  is available for only Apple Watch of iOS 8.2 and above. Please refer [iOSFonts](http://iosfonts.com) for more information.

If your are using this font in iPhone or iPad. you will get error like this.
Following code can used to find out Fonts available in current iOS version.

```
for (id familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", familyName);
        for (id fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) NSLog(@"  %@", fontName);
    }
```